Eslint and prettier with Typescript React configuration
I have recently integrated eslint and prettier with react application based on typescript. I am having an issue where when I run npm run lint, I am able to see the warnings given by eslint, but when I run npm start, the application starts without showing any error. Also, when I do ctrl + s on a particular file, then it starts showing up error of that file on npm start, same scenario goes for prettier as well.
npm start

I was expecting errors to be shown, but application started without error
npm run lint

The application shows error

please provide the error.

Please include your package.json, at least the scripts object, so that we can see what these scripts actually do.

This is because an react application doesn‘t run per default npm run lint when npm start, because eslint is an external library. Therefore you have to extend this eslint command in the package.json in the script section by the option "start".
So by npm start it‘s runs all commands together: ng serve for starting the angular application, npm run lint to helps enforce standards and npm run prettier to check formatting issues in code. This also called as dealing with parallel tasks.
package.json:
{
  "name": "my react app",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start && npm run lint && npm run prettier"
  }
}

